# Django logging errors occuring in admin page

Tags: django, django-models, admin

I face the following issue:

I want to add a new instance of a model in the django admin page, but I do get an 500 error. Now I want to log all the errors occurring in the admin page to a file.

Important details:

1. website running in production, hence I do not get feedback in the browser or the console (since I use Gunicorn).
2. this occurs only for one specific model.
3. this only happens when adding a new instance for that model, not when changing exisiting instance
4. logging in the view does not help, since error occurs within admin page

I do not want you to help me debug my django code. I am only interessted for tips and a tutorial on how to log every error occuring no matter if it happens in the admin page or the actual site. I am happy for any tips and suggestions! Thanks! Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What's the stacktrace of the 500 error? In terms of logging & how-to... start here, https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/python-logging-basics/

Comment: how can I get the stacktrace of the error ? Thanks for the link !

Comment: ohh I just found out : sudo systemctl status gunicorn 
then I could see the stacktrace. I acctually managed to solve the issue now :D Thanks!
Also thanks for the link!

Answer (score -1):

To get the stack trace of an error with gunicorn as proxy server:

sudo systemctl status gunicorn

For the logging tutorial (answer by @markwalker_):

[logging tutorial](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/python-logging-basics/)